# How to authenicate personal computers and phones?

Tags: authentication, certificates

I feel like this information should be readily available but looks like it's not:

When I buy a new laptop or phone, it seems like there's a whole set of initial connections that might require my (client) authentication. For example, if I bought a Mac, Apple might want to authenticate that the Mac I'm registering is not a hackintosh (not sure if Apple actually does this), or two-way TLS in some cases.

Does such a thing not exist? If it does, then my new laptop/phone must come shipped with a valid cert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For stuff like "registering a genuine product", the solution is simply serial numbers (which are not particularly secure, but do provide some speed bump to faking a product registration). As a general rule, though, shipping commodity hardware with a unique private key and a meaningful signed certificate is probably more effort than it's worth. What does it actually get you?

Like, sure, Apple would definitely prefer that Hackintoshes never become widespread, but it doesn't actually harm them that much if a few exist and this kind of system isn't needed to just keep the number low. Microsoft, Sony, and Nintendo want to be able to identify unique consoles on their network, and might actually bother with a system like this, but it eats into the already-poor margins on the hardware in exchange for... making it slightly more possible to ban cheaters? Microsoft and other PC/Chromebook vendors probably don't care at all; if something wants to run their software, or *pretend* to run their software, well that's fine; they distribute the software in inspectable form so there's no way to hide keys in it anyhow. Intel chips do have an embedded key that works something like this; users routinely leave it disabled or even permanently wipe it, because for most users this is a net-negative-value "feature". If Intel attempted to make it impossible to disable, this would lead to a substantial backlash against them.

Phones already have at least one unique identifier (the IMEI), though it's not a private key. It lets operators identify the model of phone on their network, and maintain lists of stolen devices, but you can still use a banned-IMEI phone as a pocket computer. I suppose Apple might want to (and might even be able to) identify iPhones that they want to keep off their store or otherwise track in some way; this isn't a practical option for Android since the software is also distributed separately from the hardware.

It's worth noting that these unique values are generally not available to third-party software. Having a unique key baked into hardware but usable by software can make DRM much easier to implement, but that doesn't make the product more appealing to any end user (Intel briefly exposed full CPU serial numbers to software; this was unpopular and quickly canned). All modern smartphone OSes prevent access to any hardware secrets (like IMEI) and only enable access to a device-wide OS-based secret (usually called an "advertising ID" or similar) with user consent.

Comment: Hmm you touched on the reason why I asked this questions, which is that I wanted to access these unique values. But I guess that's not doable.

Answer (score 1):

All new computers and phones *do* ship with certificates already installed, of course. Web browsers need CA certificates for TLS/SSL to work, and those can’t safely be downloaded over the Internet (except over a TLS connection, which you can’t establish without the certificate you need to download). Apple devices also ship with a bunch of other Apple certificates for things like iCloud and the App Stores.